# How can I make new observations from columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, dataset, tidyr

I received a dataset from a survey, and it has a rather strange structure. Every row has 90 variables, with the first 15 being general questions and the other 75 being 5 sets of 15 variables, that are actually observations. The concrete case is an employer being asked questions about employees. It holds the following structure:

```
set.seed(42) 
n <- 100
data <- data.frame(
                  EmployerVar1=1:n,,
                  EmployerVar2=rnorm(n),
                  EmployerVar3=rnorm(n),
                  EmployerVar4=rnorm(n),
                  EmployerVar5=rnorm(n),
                  EmployerVar6=rnorm(n),
                  EmployerVar7=rnorm(n),
                  EmployerVar8=rnorm(n),
                  EmployerVar9=rnorm(n),
                  EmployerVar10=rnorm(n),
                  EmployerVar11=rnorm(n),
                  EmployerVar12=rnorm(n),
                  EmployerVar13=rnorm(n),
                  EmployerVar14=rnorm(n),
                  EmployerVar15=rnorm(n),
                  Employee1Var1=rnorm(n),
                  Employee1Var2=rnorm(n),
                  Employee1Var3=rnorm(n),
                  Employee1Var4=rnorm(n),
                  Employee1Var5=rnorm(n),
                  Employee1Var6=rnorm(n),
                  Employee1Var7=rnorm(n),
                  Employee1Var8=rnorm(n),
                  Employee1Var9=rnorm(n),
                  Employee1Var10=rnorm(n),
                  Employee1Var11=rnorm(n),
                  Employee1Var12=rnorm(n),
                  Employee1Var13=rnorm(n),
                  Employee1Var14=rnorm(n),
                  Employee1Var15=rnorm(n),
                  Employee2Var1=rnorm(n),
                  Employee2Var2=rnorm(n),
                  Employee2Var3=rnorm(n),
                  Employee2Var4=rnorm(n),
                  Employee2Var5=rnorm(n),
                  Employee2Var6=rnorm(n),
                  Employee2Var7=rnorm(n),
                  Employee2Var8=rnorm(n),
                  Employee2Var9=rnorm(n),
                  Employee2Var10=rnorm(n),
                  Employee2Var11=rnorm(n),
                  Employee2Var12=rnorm(n),
                  Employee2Var13=rnorm(n),
                  Employee2Var14=rnorm(n),
                  Employee2Var15=rnorm(n),
                  Employee3Var1=rnorm(n),
                  Employee3Var2=rnorm(n),
                  Employee3Var3=rnorm(n),
                  Employee3Var4=rnorm(n),
                  Employee3Var5=rnorm(n),
                  Employee3Var6=rnorm(n),
                  Employee3Var7=rnorm(n),
                  Employee3Var8=rnorm(n),
                  Employee3Var9=rnorm(n),
                  Employee3Var10=rnorm(n),
                  Employee3Var11=rnorm(n),
                  Employee3Var12=rnorm(n),
                  Employee3Var13=rnorm(n),
                  Employee3Var14=rnorm(n),
                  Employee3Var15=rnorm(n),
                  Employee4Var1=rnorm(n),
                  Employee4Var2=rnorm(n),
                  Employee4Var3=rnorm(n),
                  Employee4Var4=rnorm(n),
                  Employee4Var5=rnorm(n),
                  Employee4Var6=rnorm(n),
                  Employee4Var7=rnorm(n),
                  Employee4Var8=rnorm(n),
                  Employee4Var9=rnorm(n),
                  Employee4Var10=rnorm(n),
                  Employee4Var11=rnorm(n),
                  Employee4Var12=rnorm(n),
                  Employee4Var13=rnorm(n),
                  Employee4Var14=rnorm(n),
                  Employee4Var15=rnorm(n),
                  Employee5Var1=rnorm(n),
                  Employee5Var2=rnorm(n),
                  Employee5Var3=rnorm(n),
                  Employee5Var4=rnorm(n),
                  Employee5Var5=rnorm(n),
                  Employee5Var6=rnorm(n),
                  Employee5Var7=rnorm(n),
                  Employee5Var8=rnorm(n),
                  Employee5Var9=rnorm(n),
                  Employee5Var10=rnorm(n),
                  Employee5Var11=rnorm(n),
                  Employee5Var12=rnorm(n),
                  Employee5Var13=rnorm(n),
                  Employee5Var14=rnorm(n),
                  Employee5Var15=rnorm(n))
```

For analysis the dataset needs to have every observation in a new row, being the employer characteristics with the 15 variables linked to one employee. So the number of rows needs to increase fivefold.

I asked this question once before and while I thought this was the solution, it eventually didn't work. The suggestion was to:

```
library(tidyr)

X_wide <- data.frame(id = 1:3, P1 = 4:6, P2 = 7:9, P3 = 10:12)
X_long <- pivot_longer(X_wide, cols = P1:P3, names_to = "person", values_to = "score")
X_long <- as.data.frame(X_long)
```

This does not work as it would collapse all observation-columns in one new variable. All the data needs to remain the same, it only needs to land in a new spot. To clarify, this is the structure that I would need for analysis.

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EmployerVar1 | EmployerVar2 | EmployerVar3 | Employee1Var1 | Employee1Var2 | Employee1Var3 |
| EmployerVar1 | EmployerVar2 | EmployerVar3 | Employee2Var1 | Employee2Var2 | Employee2Var3 |
| EmployerVar1 | EmployerVar2 | EmployerVar3 | Employee3Var1 | Employee3Var2 | Employee3Var3 |

Comment: Can you provide a minimal version of your dataset with `data.frame()` or can you turn your data into code with `dput()`? It'd be easier for us to understand what it looks like and try some code.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible :( It holds mostly categorical variables and also sensitive information. So I'm not allowed to share it.

Comment: I understand - in this case, can you create a minimal reproducible dataset (fake data but in the same format as your dataset) with `data.frame()`? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), section "Providing a minimal dataset", subsection "Data frames".

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I'm new to Stackoverflow, so learning that this is expected is interesting. I added a data.frame() in my original post. I hope this will help in figuring out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to reshape the data **slightly** longer.

This is not a simple `pivot_longer()` because:

1. There are some columns that you don't need to reshape - the only columns that need reshaping start with `Employee`. You can fix this by using `starts_with()`.
2. The columns that need reshaping contain 2 parts: the first part (`Employee`) needs to create new rows, but the second part (`Question`) needs to stay in separate columns. For this, you can use `separate()` to split the two parts, and `pivot_wider()`.

To show you a possible solution, I recreated a *minimum reproducible dataset* from scratch.

The problem can be simplified to a **minimum** dataset of:

- two rows (one for employer)
- two columns that will stay the same
- four columns that will need reshaping (2 per employee and 2 per question)

The sample data you provided is different to your actual data: you used `rnorm()` to simulate all columns, but you said in the comments that your dataset actually contains mostly categorical data. This is relevant because having different data types will complicate the pivotting. I made an assumption that your dataset contains only categorical or numeric columns.

I also slightly changed `Var` into `.Qst` so that it was clearer to me what they meant, and it was easier to split the employee part from the question number part.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(
  EmployerVar1 = c("a", "b"),
  EmployerVar2 = c("d", "e"),
  Employee1.Qst1 = c("A", "B"),
  Employee1.Qst2 = c(1.5, 2.5),
  Employee2.Qst1 = c("F", "G"),
  Employee2.Qst2 = c(-6,-7)
)

dat |> 
  # Change all numerical columns to character
  mutate(across(where(is.double), as.character)) |> 
  # Pivot longer
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Employee"),
               names_to = "Employee.Qst") |>
  # Split 
  separate(col = Employee.Qst, c("Employee", "Question")) |> 
  # Pivot wider
  pivot_wider(names_from = Question, 
              values_from = value)
```

PS I really recommend going through [the pivoting vignette](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html) from `tidyr`, it's really helpful.